# imu "buffer length" is zero

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a differential drive mobile robot.

I  am using mpu9250 IMU with this package [jeskesen /i2c_imu](https://github.com/jeskesen/i2c_imu)

thr `tf_tree` is as shown in [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qx03kbFGf7AMi6N0zYTI-SSsXIocoW_P/view?usp=sharing)

the `tf_tree` show that the  imu :

"Average rate" is 10000,

"Buffer length" is zero,

"Oldest transform" is zero ,

**Edit 1 :**
The imu frame comes from mpu9250 IMU "it is the real imu" not from robot_state_publisher.

and what is deference between my `tf_tree` [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qx03kbFGf7AMi6N0zYTI-SSsXIocoW_P/view?usp=sharing) and others project in this links  [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zIsRAICjcxMuaViqopPwqHfTcImE5hFx/view?usp=sharing)  [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16d2l6mKwdQyiPf25NC6N0ZHTiqXuG6wM/view?usp=sharing) [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DxumQ0DRIuoUWNQvy1C1sgxO0j2E6nnL/view?usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361094/imu-%22buffer-length%22-is-zero/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf_tree shows buffer zero because I activate the imu_link and base_link transformation in the urdf file.

and this overwrite the real imu package transformation.

When I deactivate "comment"  this transformation from urdf file. It is works and the imu buffer is 0.697.

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) with karma: 23 on 2020-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1